# Access Denied Error for Administrator in MOSS 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am getting the following error for MOSS 2007 site although I am logged in as a site administrator.

```
You do not have access right and should contact the administrator
```

Kindly help me out.

Comment: You'll need to contact the Site Collection Administrator (SCA). A site administrator doesn't have overriding rights to everything. The SCA does though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a right to Central Administration ? 
IF yes, then SignIn to the central administration and

Click on **Application Management > Under Site Collection Section > Click on Change Site Collection Administrators**.

Select your application url from the Site Collections list:

Now view the Primary and Secondary Site Collection administrators for your application.

If the your name is not listed in there then **select your name and Click OK**.

Now again try to access your site .

Thanks